# HTML Appearance changes with scrollbar does not always show

Tags: html, scrollbar

I am currently working with HTML and have added scroll bars to my pages, no problem. I've also change the appearance of the scroll bar with:

```
<div style="
height: 610px; 
width: 550px; 
border: 0px solid #ccc; 
font: 12px trebuchet MS; 
overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; 
scrollbar-face-color: #ffffff; 
scrollbar-highlight-color: #ffffff; 
scrollbar-3dlight-color: #ffffff; 
scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #ffffff; 
scrollbar-shadow-color: #ffffff; 
scrollbar-arrow-color: #1C3F94; 
scrollbar-track-color: #ffffff;
">
```

And it works! sometimes... when my friends sees the website or when i sometime log on the scroll bar reverts back to a standard windows appearance. I haven't change any of the coding and don't understand why does it work in some occasions and not in other.

Thanks 
Emily

Comment: some browsers like IE6-IE8 are not compatible or there is problem in website loading due to internet speed

Comment: i see, but the same error appears even when i use the same internet or same laptop... so how would i fix it?

i'm looking at the developer tool, and on the CSS style side there's a little ! "unknown property name", this wasn't a problem yesterday , why now :(

Comment: can u post some more code?

Comment: yes of cause :) ... umm what code would you like to see? I'm working in HTML and CSS... the code above is in my html page (on wordpress)

Comment: you  want scrolls to be shown everytime?

Comment: yes shown all the time ... basically in this box is the news, so the further you scroll down the older the news... there's enough text/images in this 610x550 box for the scroll to activate...
functionally it's working fine..

but now i want to change the colours of each component (leaving only the arrows blue) 

hopefully i've explain well enough :)

Comment: try using iframe it can be good

Comment: I've looked in to iframe and thank you for showing me this code, it looks very useful.

.... but according to some chats between people, iframe can only display scrs and pages, i only wanted to display a table of information or some images, is this not possible then?

Answer (score 0):

Use follwing code for iframe

```
 <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
<p><a href="grasphub.com" target="iframe_a">grasphub.com</a></p>
```

Create a file where place html code which you want to show in ifram say **demo_iframe.htm**

then copy paste above code and you can change width and height of it easily.